# How to fix Print problems on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, libreoffice

i have OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and printer Epson stylus dx 4050. Printer was fine and same with the Ubuntu until yesterday when i had to change one cartridge for Red color on the printer. 
  The problem is that Ubuntu does not follow the order to print any document on Office Libre. If the printer is attached to an other computer OS windows xp then it prints any document. Which means something is wrong with the Ubuntu, Office libre.
  How to fix the printing problem?

Thanks I.M.

Comment: I had a similar problem. For me somehow the properties of the printer had changed. There was a checkbox "Disable printer" or "Activated" or something like that. Changing this checkbox in the properties and the printer worked again.

Comment: Nope, there is no such option at Printer properties

Comment: If you go to the Epson icon in the PRINTERS folder; right-click; left-column; there are a list of things; top line is SETTINGS;  under SETTINGS; is POLICIES and ACCESS CONTROL; I think IQV is suggesting checking through all those many options in POLICIES and ACCESS CONTROL .. however whilst there, if you start at the top option; SETTINGS; if you come down to MAKE & MODEL and drag the window to the right; can you copy and paste what is in that MAKE & MODEL window please?

Comment: I got a Canon LBP6230dw and when I troubleshoot it says what the Diagnostic Output is but it is too long to post here. It does not provide a solution.

Comment: Please add more explanations to your questions, not as an answer. I think it will be possible to post the diagnostic outputs somewhere else and mention the HTTPS link to readers. Good luck